# Loading a .csv file into dictionary, I keep getting the error "cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'"

Tags: c#, dictionary, streamreader

I've used streamreader to read in a .csv file, then i need to split the values and put them into a dictionary. so far i have:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("textwords0.csv"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                dict.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I keep getting the error "cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'" but cant work out how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

update:
...I accidentally left the csv file open and its working now,  sorry for wasting time guys thought i had a different spreadsheet open, some very useful advice though thanks for all the help!

Comment: Which line gives you the error? The dict.Add line?

Comment: Can we view de source? (textwords0.csv)?

Comment: VS is saying line 33 which is the last }.

Comment: Not sure if you solved this yet, but are you sure you are getting the exception you wrote in the question?  I just ran this on some random data, and it worked just fine

Comment: Use a [CsvParser](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper), there are pretty good 3rd parties that take care of edge cases you haven't even thought of.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you're using <kbd>.NET 4.0</kbd>, the following is really succinct and should accomplish the same thing:

```
var dict = File.ReadLines("textwords0.csv").Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(line => line[0], line => line[1]);
```

Comment: not sure this would work if you have data with ',' in them. you need csv parser here.

Comment: this is fragile as the value could be wrapped in quotes if it contains a comma `("this is, a value")` - the value will be split in half

Comment: That's true about it not checking if the comma is in a quote or the data, but @jesusjuice doesn't seem worried about that.

Comment: You could try using a regex like the following:  var rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\"(.*?)\"|,");

rgx.Split("open,\"drive, over the , moon\",kriston");

Comment: This fails if the CSV file has fields that contain commas enclosed in quotes, which is a very common scenario. Ex: `"This is 1st column, that also has a comma inside, so excel encloses column value in quotes",This is 2nd column no comma inside.`

Answer (score 0):

the error is actually because of the ',' you are inputting. It needs an "array" of characters to split from. Here is an example method of splitting using string.split.

```
string[] parts = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Hope this helps.
this is presuming this is the line the error is coming from as you havn't specified.

Comment: apparently its line 33 which is the last }. I'm fairly new to programming in general so finding this slightly confusing. Thanks!